# Dynamic database connection/initialization in typeorm `0.3.6` with Express

Tags: node.js, express, typeorm

`typeorm 0.3.6` deprecated `createConnections()` and and introduced `DataSource`. It is causing some issues with multi-tenant architecture.

Either I have to `initialize()` all the data sources with different databases in the bootstrap `index.ts` or have to `initialize()` the Datasource much later where I have access to `req`. Because based on a request parameter, I know which database to use.

Is it possible to dynamically initialize all the data sources during bootstrap in `index.ts`? Currently, I do like

```
Promise.all([dss.AppDataSource.initialize(), dss.AppDataSource2.initialize()])
.then((values) => {
  //console.log(values);
  console.log('... ... ... all Database initialized');
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error(error.message)
});
```

Comment: did you get an answer?